# Relative path for XCopy ../ throwing error 4

Tags: cmd, xcopy

I've the following Strange error with Xcopy that does not accept the ../ for parent directory and gives off an error 4

The same ../ works well on a chdir or cd command

Error   1   The command "`xcopy "D:\Code\Main\src\..\Debug\*.*" "D:\Code\Main\src\..\Release" /ciyr`" exited with code 4.   D:\Code\Main\src\SetupDependentPlugins\SetupThirdPartyPlugins.csproj    134 5   SetupThirdPartyPlugins

> C:\User>

```
xcopy "D:\Code\Main\src\
..\Debug\*.*" "D:\Code\Main\src\..\Release" /ciyr
```

> File not found - *.* 0 File(s) copied
>
> C:\User>

```
xcopy "D:\Code\Main\src\
..\Debug\*.*" "D:\Code\Main\src\..\Release" /ciyr
```

> File not found - *.* 0 File(s) copied
>
> C:\User>

```
chdir "D:\Code\Main\src\..\"
```

> C:\User>d:

D:\Code\Main>

The same command when run on VisualStudio CMD Prompt gives an error file not found but there are files inside the folders mentioned

Comment: `C:\Windows\system32>net helpmsg 4

The system cannot open the file.`  Your path is wrong. Your quotes are wrong. `..` is a directory -it needs a backspace before and after.

Comment: please edit your code using `{}` to format. Your original source code shows `...src\ ..\Debug...` but the code displayed is missing the first `\`. This is because of markdown's interpetation of the required strins.

Comment: @Magoo formatting complete